# flipping arguments in the "->"statement

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

the code following code does not work because re-find accepts a string as the first argument and a regex as the second.

```
(-> "hello"
    .toUpperCase
    (re-find #".$"))
```

The code would work if I wrapped re-find like this:

```
(defn re-find2 [s r]
   (re-find r s))
```

If I replace re-find with re-find2 now, I get what I expected: a capitalized "O".

How could I solve this without wrapping re-find?

Comment: Note that you probably wanted to say the opposite in the first sentence, more like: *re-find accepts a **regex** as the first argument and a **string** as the second.*

Comment: You might also like `(as-> ... )`

Comment: In the event `->>` wasn't here to help, you don't need to do things like `re-find2` to solve the problem. Instead, you can use an inline lambda `#(re-find %2 %1)` to flip the parameters. Knowing this might help you in the future.

Comment: Can you please mark an answer as valid? Your question has been answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case you could use the [thread-last](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro instead.

```
(->> "hello" .toUpperCase (re-find #".$"))
```

If you really need to switch between passing as first and last argument you can chain the threading macros:

```
(-> "hello" .toUpperCase (->> (re-find #".$")))
```

Comment: ah, yes! But how would it be, if last parameter forms and first parameter forms are mixed. Actually I have some more forms before .toUpperCase which are first parameter forms.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned, you can use thread-last if all your functions only have one argument or take the result as the last argument. However, if you also have functions which have multiple arguments and you must pass the result in a specific position which cannot be handled by -> or ->>, then possibly the as-> macro would be your best bet.

This macro allows you to specify a binding for the result from each function call. As the result now has a name, you can control where that parameter is positioned. Have a look at [this blog post on threading macros](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2015/11/09/lesser-known-clojure-variants-of-threading-macro/)